# IntelliJ Python Facet vs Python Module

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, intellij-idea, intellij-15

In IntelliJ, I have a Java project (JAVA_MODULE) that also has some Python code. The python code imports numpy, scipy and some other libraries.

If I set my Module type to Python, all the import works and there is no squiggly lines. If I set my module type to Java, then add a Python facet, there are squiggly lines for imports of any non-standard libraries. i.e. import of os and sys works but numpy, scipy aren't.

Is there a difference in PYTHONPATH for Python Facet and Python Module?

Comment: Did you select a Python interpreter in your Python facet? Was it the same one that you selected in the module?

Comment: Yes I did. Same one.

Comment: Oddly, I get the opposite - it's the standard libraries that have squiggles, while the 3rd-parties import, but then fail to resolve any of their contents.